# What's the best way to create a two-level library, containing a class with different levels of abilities?

Tags: c#, design, libraries

I would like to create a library consisting of two layers, lets call them A and B. There should be a class "Sample" in layer A. Layer B also knows about class "Sample" and enlarges it by some methods.

Then I would like to have another project, referencing this library, so I can have the following scenarios for an instance of "Sample", lets call it sample_instance:

```
1) using A;
```

Typing "sample_instance.", Intellisense will show me all the methods that are defined in layer A.

```
2) using B;
```

Typing "sample_instance.", Intellisense will show me all the methods that are defined in layer B.

```
3) using A;
   using B;
```

Typing "sample_instance.", Intellisense will show me all the methods that are defined in layer A and B.

I've been thinking about this many days now but I'm not able to find a proper solution. I've been experimenting with extension methods in layer B, which gets Scenario 1) and 3) to work. But I can't realise 2) this way, because the project doesn't know the class "Sample" if I only do "using B".

Does someone have a good idea, how to design it?

Comment: If the user wants to user layer B, is he supposed to not know that layer A exists? What goals are you trying to achieve with this design? Maybe you need an additional basic module that defines a very raw Sample class. Then, A and B are siblings in the dependency graph referencing on the basic module.

Comment: He knows about layer A and B but can choose which one he wants to use. So layer A provides a basic set of methods, layer B a higher level. But he should also be able to use both if he wants. What do you mean by siblings, two different classes, inheriting from the base module?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Comment: Why do you bother what Intellisense is showing you? It is means to help development, not drive it. It should be compiler who makes sure that A functionality can only be called when A layer is referenced and same for B.

Answer (score 1):

[Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) should do the trick. You can get Scenario 2 to work by redefining your `Sample` class in the second layer through inheritance. Something like

```
namespace A
{
    public class Sample { ... }

    public static class SampleExtensions 
    {
        public static void Foo(this Sample sample, ...) { ... }
        ...
    }
}

namespace B
{
    public class Sample : A.Sample { ... }

    public static class SampleExtensions 
    {
        public static void Bar(this Sample sample, ...) { ... }
        ...
    }
}
```

That way, `using A;` should show you all the methods defined in `A.SampleExtensions` and `A.Sample`, `using B;` should show you all the methods defined in `B.SampleExtensions` and `B.Sample` (and by inheritance `A.Sample`) and `using A; using B;` should show you all of them.

Note that the latter introduces an ambiguity on the type name `Sample` which can be resolved by either adding `using Sample = A.Sample` or by defining the `Sample` class in a different namespace altogether.

Also, depending on your requirements it might be wise to define the extension methods in `B.SampleExtensions` to extend the type `A.Sample` instead of `Sample` (which is `B.Sample`), that is

```
public static void Bar(this A.Sample sample, ...) { ... }
```

Otherwise an instance of `A.Sample` can't use an extension method defined in `B.SampleExtensions`even with `using B;`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should think about using inheritance...

1. Make class A the parent, and it contains one public instance *sample_instance*.
2. Make classes B and C the children, so they will inherit the public instance *sample_instance*.

Note: In-turn, intellisense will show you the public *sample_instance* as a member of classses A, B, and C.